# Finding specific feature class in multiple geodatabase using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, esri-geodatabase, feature-class

I have multiple geodatabase and shapefiles in multiple sub folders. I would like to search the feature class with keyword “building”, and then export all of them into a single geodatabase with multiple feature classes.  For now I assume the “buildings” are polygons but they could be in poly lines or points but I want to fetch them as long as their names contains the keyword “%building%”.

Is there any chance I can do it using ModelBuilder?

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Iterate Feature Classes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-classes.htm). If you study the help file you will see that it has a parameter *Recursive*, which when ticked on will recursively traverse all sub-folders.